# Why am I getting a type error from this function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to create a drop down menu in tkinter that allows the user to select a machine, or row # from the excel sheet, and then all the data from that entire row is displayed in tkinter through the display_selected function. I keep getting this error.
This is my error:

```
 TypeError: line_7_window.<locals>.display_selected() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This is my code:

```
def get_machine():
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=60):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == inputmachine:
                machineindex = cell
                return machineindex.row

def get_machineattributes():
    for col in sheet.iter_cols(min_row = (get_machine()), max_col = 15, max_row = (get_machine())):
        for cell in col:
            return (cell.value)

def display_selected():   
    data = Message(line_7, text=get_machineattributes())
    data.pack()
    data.place(x=650, y=30)

    copy = Button(line_7, text="Copy to Clipboard", command=pyperclip.copy(line7_choice))
    copy.pack()
    copy.place(x=550, y=45)
    return


inputmachine = StringVar(line_7)
inputmachine.set("Click to select a machine")
dropdown = OptionMenu(line_7, inputmachine, *lst, command=display_selected)
dropdown.pack()
dropdown.place(x=670, y=25)
```

I have tried everything and I cant figure out why this would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function `display_selected`, specified when creating the option menu, will receive the actual option chosen from Tk, so you need that parameter when defining it, even if you do nothing with it.

In other words, use something like:

```
   def display_selected(choice):
       del choice  # not used
       # rest of function
```

As an aside, I suspect you may be better off with an option menu to select the item, and a separate button to act on that selection. That would allow you to confirm the selected item before performing any action, in case you inadvertently choose the wrong one.

Comment: that seems to work, thanks. Do you have any idea how I could make this work? I was iterating through each row in the 1st column because that is where the machine title was, and when it finds a cell with a value that matches the users input I selected that row and then printed out that whole row. Atleast, that was my thought process. Actually doing it is a lot harder. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @bradenzingler, depends on what you're using to process the worksheet. The process you describe is workable though you'll need to be able to figure out which row the data ends on (eg blank cell). I'd do that simple one first and worry about optimising only if it becomes an issue.

Comment: Should I open up another question and post all my code along with what I am overall trying to do? I am kinda new to stack overflow so I didnt know if people wouldnt like that. Also, I am using open pyxl.

Comment: That's the usual practice, yes, though you may want to post only enough code to illustrate the issue (no-one like massive code dumps). A lot more people see questions than comments :-)

Comment: I drafted up a question but I can only post once every ninety minutes. Do you want me to let you know when I post?

Comment: @bradenzingler: sure, I'll have a crack at it if no-one gets to it with a decent answer beforehand. But, I've been at work for the last 8 hours and it's still not posted so I'll just fave this and come back every so often to your questions.